# Import classes from sub-module of a multi-module maven project

Tags: maven, multi-module

I have a multi-module maven project and I have issues with importing classes from sub-module. Below is an example

Module B has dependency to C and D

And module A has dependency to B.

Now from module A I would like to access classes from C or D without adding them as dependencies to A because they are already added in B.

But I couldn't import them in classes from module A. Any clue for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your POMs please

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I have added a reply instead. I couldn't properly format the code in the comment.

Comment: You can edit the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there should be no technical barrier that hinders you from using transitive dependencies directly (you can configure the dependency plugin to avoid this, though).

But note that this is not a recommended practise. If you use a class, declare the artifact/module as dependency, regardless whether it is already a transitive dependency. Your solution is brittle because you rely on other modules to have these dependencies and this may change in the future.